# writing Java classes that represent intervals and lists of intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, class, intervals

Is this a relatively good solution to the following problem:

> Considering that CInterval can implement any interval: (a,b), and 
>       CIntervalList implements a reunion of distinct intervals, it is required
>        to write an IntervalList method that intersects two intervals.

If there are better ways to design the two classes, can you please offer suggestions?
What if the union is required? The union of an interval is not always an interval, so how would you change the return type of the method?
If you have better suggestions for designing the class, it would help to at least give the method signatures, if not the entire body. Many thanks in advance.
PS. Why do you think CIntervalList is required? I could have had a method called intersect inside CInterval itself, with a method such as:
`CInterval intersection(CInterval x)` that could be called like this `Interval3 = Interval1.intersection(Interval2)`

```
class CInterval
{
    int a;
    int b;
    boolean vd = false; //(void intervals are marked with vd = true)
}

class CIntervalList
{
    CInterval intersection(CInterval x, CInterval y)
    {
        CInterval z = new CInterval();

        if(x.vd == false || y.vd = false) 
        {
            z.vd= true;
            return z;
        }
        else if(x.a < y.a)
        {
            if(x.b < y.a)
            {
                z.vd= true;
                return z;
            } else
            {
                if(x.b < y.b)
                {
                    z.a = y.a;
                    z.b = x.b;
                    return z;
                }
                else
                {
                    z.a = y.a;
                    z.b = y.b;
                    return z;
                }
            }
        } else if(x.a > y.a)
        {
            if(y.b < x.a)
            {
                z.vd= true;
                return z;
            } else
            {
                if(y.b < x.b)
                {
                    z.a = x.a;
                    z.b = y.b;
                    return z;
                }
                else
                {
                    z.a = x.a;
                    z.b = x.b;
                    return z;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All those `z.boolean` references should be `z.vd`.  And what's the meaning of this field?

Comment: " CInterval intersection(CInterval x, CInterval y)" is expected to be `static` that's way it is in `CIntervalList`, like `Files`, `Collections`, `Paths` ....

Comment: Thank you , don Roby. I edited my question with your correction. vd is used to mark an interval void, in case it is void. I didn't know how else to show that an interval is void, other than creating a field that flags it as such.

Comment: **remark** : `a` and `b` are not so meaningful ! rather use *bornSup* and *bornInf* or *left* and *right* or even *up* and *down* :) or **end** and **start**

Comment: is `b` always >= `a` (when interval isn't void...)?

Comment: Yes, Amit. I started with that assumption, that a <= b always.

Comment: If you wish to post this on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you will most certainly get a better chance for good feedback on your design (I will be happy to help, too).

Answer (score 0):

### bunch of remarks

- `CInterval intersection(CInterval x, CInterval y)` is expected to be **static** that's why it is in `CIntervalList` like `Files`in Java or `Collections`, `Paths` ...
- **a** and **b** are not so *meaningful* ! rather use bornSup and bornInf or left and right or **end** and **start**.
- create a constructor with parameters for `CInterval` ... `public CInterval(int a,int b, boolean vd)`
- have you thought using `Math.min` and `Math.max` ?
- When you access an instance variable `vd` like this `z.vd = ...` you are not taking in consideration the encapsulation oo principal. Try to set Getters and Setters for you class `CInterval`.
- if one of the intervals is Void, in this case set the **z** interval to Void one, so `if(x.vd == true || y.vd = true)`
- no need to write this `} else if(x.a > y.a)` just `}else` suffice.

**PS** : But between I think your question fits more in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The intersection function can be much simpler, like this:

```
CInterval intersection(CInterval x, CInterval y)
{
   CInterval z = new CInterval();

   if(x.vd == false || y.vd = false) 
   {
      z.vd= true;
      return z;
   }

   z.a = Math.max(x.a, y.a);
   z.b = Math.min(x.b, y.b);
   z.vd = z.a <= z.b;

   return z;
}
```

However, your solution might be better optimized for speed. In a tight loop situation it might be worth to be that verbose, but in general, readability & maintainabilty are preffered.